# Streaming Video From Server Using VLC CLI

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming

Currently, I have a server with a bunch of home movies on it. These home movies are anywhere from 720p to 1080p. The bit rate of these videos is too high for me to stream via a simple "open the http stream in the media player on my phone." The way I'm getting around this for now is by using HandBrakeCLI to do batch conversions to lower qualities that can then easily be watched on my phone (or desktop, or TV, etc).

However, I'm looking for a way to do the transcoding "live", so I don't have to wait while the video is converted from one format to another. I believe there's a way to make this happen using VLC or FFMpeg, but I don't know how, and my Google-fu is failing to return results.

Does anyone know of a simple way to do just-in-time-transcoding-and-streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Plex Media Server](http://www.plexapp.com/). You can install an app on almost any device, and you can set the bitrate you wish to stream at on the device itself, instead of the server.  Read more about the transcoding [here](http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/PlexNine_AdvancedInfo#Understanding_a_Transcode_Session).